# start shell command on non root devices

Tags: android, shell, adb, root

I'm very new in android development

I have a non-root devices and a small script which executes by adb

```
adb shell am start-activity --display 2 ru.yandex.yandexnavi/.core.NavigatorActivity
```

However I need to execute it directly on a device

I tried to download terminal on android device and execute it in terminal

```
am start-activity --display 2 ru.yandex.yandexnavi/.core.NavigatorActivity
```

and of course I get a message

> Exception occurred while executing 'start-activity: java.lang. SecurityException: Permission Denial: package=com.android.shell does not belong to uid=10211

In this case I don't have opportunity to root my devices, but maybe here's some another ways to make this code execute on a device?

am start-activity --display 2 ru.yandex.yandexnavi/.core.NavigatorActivity

Comment: Apps can start exported intents of other apps directly without `am start-activity`. See e.g. sample apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrefrsousa.tools.activitymanager

Comment: it could be very helpful, but here's a trick that I need to run this activity on a secondary display so I write in a command '--display 2'. how I checked these apps I can't modify their run command by adding '--display' parameter

Comment: There are also apps available which allow you to manually craft the whole intent including extended options, so adding the display option should be possible (even if I don't know at the moment tk which option it is translated to). If you are not a total beginner in development you could try to develop your own mini Android app that exactly executes the intent you need. And how tk start an intent for opening an activity in a different app is discussed quite a few times here on SO.